# How I can put the text of the table in two lines?

Tags: tables

I wanna make a table with a large text but I can't put the text in two or more lines because the text in the document is cut.
I put this in LATEX:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
Per\'{i}odo (s) & Valores e aproxima\c{c}\~{o}es (s) \\
\midrule
$T=T_0\biggl(1+\frac{1}{4}\sin^2(\frac{\theta_0}{2})+\frac{9}
{64}\sin^4(\frac{\theta_0}{2})+...$ & Express\~{a}o exata \\

$T_0=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}$ & Express\~{a}o simplificada \\

1 \% & Aproxima\c{c}\~{a}o da express\~{a}o ($\sin^2 \theta \approx \theta^2)$ e soma do n\'{u}mero 1 com a primeira parcela da s\'{e}rie \\

8\% & Aproxima\c{c}\~{a}o da express\~{a}o atrav\'{e}s da soma do n\'{u}mero 1 com a primeira parcela da s\'{e}rie  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1):

For multiline cells you need to declare appropriate column type, as `p{<width>}` or `m{<width>}` (from array package) or use `tabularx` package and appropriate accommodate `X` column type. With last mentioned option you will obtain:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}% <-- new
\usepackage{ragged2e}% <-- new
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}% <-- new

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cL}
    \toprule
Per\'{i}odo (s) & Valores e aproxima\c{c}\~{o}es (s)        \\
    \midrule
$T=T_0\biggl(1+\frac{1}{4}\sin^2(\frac{\theta_0}{2})+\frac{9}
{64}\sin^4(\frac{\theta_0}{2})+...$ & Express\~{a}o exata   \\

$T_0=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}$ & Express\~{a}o simplificada   \\

1 \% & Aproxima\c{c}\~{a}o da express\~{a}o ($\sin^2 \theta \approx \theta^2)$ e soma do n\'{u}mero 1 com a primeira parcela da s\'{e}rie         \\

8\% & Aproxima\c{c}\~{a}o da express\~{a}o atrav\'{e}s da soma do n\'{u}mero 1 com a primeira parcela da s\'{e}rie                               \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

---

Short explanation/answer to your comment.
`tabular` is standard LaTeX environment for setting simple tables. More advanced is `tabularx`, which require to defining table width and then itself calculate width of columns of type `X`. In cells in this columns the content is justified, what can become ugly if the column width is small. In such a case is better to left align. This can be done with defining of new column type (as it is in above MWE) with simple `\raggedright`, which not allow hyphenation of words or by `RaggedRight` provided by package `ragged2e`, which provide smart left aligning with hyphenation longer words.

For correct hyphenation you need to load `babel` package for used language (this is not done in above MWE). If you will add it, probably some words in multilined cells will be hyphenated.

Comment: I am beginner on LATEX. Can you explain me please what is the difference between tabular and tabularx and what is the package ragged2e? I never use the command: \newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}% <-- new. What meaning this command?

Comment: See edit of my answer.